# Need to execute 'git remote prune origin' on where Jenkins gets the Jenkinsfile, but where is it?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline has the 'Prune stale remote-tracking branches' additional behavior but I guess this is only executed on the workspaces in the agent the pipeline itself will be run on. I'm talking about the initial git call made by Jenkins to get the Jenkinsfile from the repository. Does anybody have an idea where is it?

1. I tried executing 'git remote prune origin' on the agent's workspace
2. I tried disabling lightweight checkout so the repository gets cloned in the built-in node, it did not work
3. I tried adding the 'Wipe out repository and force clone' but it only applies to the workspace

Comment: Are you pulling Jenkinsfile or json file from git and are they in same repo as project. Then the jenkinsfile should be available in pipeline folder in workspace

Comment: The Jenkinsfile is located in the repository. In the pipeline configuration, the pipeline definition is set to use "Pipeline script from SCM" > "Git" > "Branch to build" > "Script Path", the lightweight checkout is set so that only the Jenkinsfile is extracted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I deleted the git folders in $JENKINS_HOME/caches/ and it worked.